# Unsafe Variable Initialization?

Tags: c#, java, c, security, optimization

I am preparing for a security exam and found a point which stated to avoid **Unsafe Variable Initialization**.
Can any one please explain me with an example (in any programming language) what type of initialization will become unsafe??

Providing more inputs from my research: 
Unsafe variable initialization should not be followed as per security coding standards. The words may not tell anything but after my research, for project requirements there are cases when you have to use calls that interact directly with the operating system(which are generally taken care by a JVM, CLR without user intervention) like memory allocations etc.
And the second point is related to what @Soner has commented -->  msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx.

Sorry for the confusion with the words variable initialization, it also confused me and that is the reason why I posted it as a question.

Comment: For C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx

Comment: Even google doesn't know the term `Unsafe Variable Initialization`

Comment: Here is an [entire article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2363/Unsafe-programming-in-C) devoted to the subject.

Comment: I don't think this is related to `java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what is meant looks like this

```
int variable;
for(int i=0; i++; i<4){
     variable+=i; //Compilation error, garbage or expected result, depending on language
}
```

In this case variable does not have an initial value and MAY be equal to zero. Or may contain garbage. Some languages disallow this (java local variables) or at least give you a warning. Some other languages allow this and guarantee initial value to be zero or null (java instance fields).
http://blog.ajduke.in/2012/03/25/variable-initialization-and-default-values/